# First Chern class of zero locus of a pairing

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, characteristic-classes, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Let $E\to X$ and $F\to Y$ be vector bundles over (sufficiently nice) surfaces or 3-folds.

If I know that a divisor $D \subset X\times Y$ is the zero locus of a pairing $\alpha\colon E \otimes F \to \mathbb{C}$, can I say something about the first Chern class of the divisor $c_1(D)$?

Comment: What do you mean by the zero locus of a pairing?

Comment: $Z(\alpha) = \alpha^{-1}(0)$

Comment: Why do you think it is a divisor?